# Processing Contact Form

Tags: php, validation

I am adding a contact page to my website, but having issues with the comment text box. When the user enters invalid information into the name and email text field, the website redirects the user back to the contact page to fill out the correct information. However, I want the comment box to be optional for the user. For example, the user will enter their name and email, but doesn't have any comments. The code should then process the information. Currently, my code will redirect the user back to the contact page because the user did not enter any information into the comment box. Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Thanks!

```
if (empty($_REQUEST['comment'])) {
    $error = TRUE;

} else {
    $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];
    $form['comment'] = $comment;
    if (!preg_match("/^.{0,50}$/", $comment)) {
        $error = TRUE;
        $messages['comment'] = "<p class='errorMessage'> You have entered invalid information.</p>";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['comment'] = $comment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow the content box to be empty, just let an empty value be an acceptable value. This means only running your validation against that field if there is a value present. This means removing your if/else statement since `empty($_REQUEST['comment'])` is no longer a valid check.

```
if (!empty($comment) && !preg_match("/^.{0,50}$/", $comment)) {
```

I just added `!empty($comment) &&` to your check which basically says, "if there is a value go ahead and validate it".

One thing you should also do if you use this code is trim whitespace from your comment box values. Otherwise a user could type a space character and that would not be considered empty:

```
$comment = trim($_REQUEST['comment']);
```

Final code:

```
$comment = trim($_REQUEST['comment']);
$form['comment'] = $comment; // I am assuming this is used elsewhere
if (!empty($comment) && !preg_match("/^.{0,50}$/", $comment)) {
    $error = TRUE;
    $messages['comment'] = "<p class='errorMessage'> You have entered invalid information.</p>";
} else {
    $_SESSION['comment'] = $comment;
}
```

Comment: So I should remove everything in the "else" statement?

Comment: You can remove your if/else and not automatically assign an error if that value is empty. Let me add that to my answer.